# Firebase child_added creates duplicates

Tags: firebase

I am using Firebase to develop an  HTML5 mobile messaging app. I encountered an issue that I am unable to resolve. The app has multiple  channels (chat rooms). When a message is added for the first time to a channel it works as expected but when I go to a different channel and post an new message to that channel then I return to the previous channel and post another message I get duplicates of the last posted message. When I reload the page the duplicates are gone but I'd prefer not to have  duplicates showing at all. Below is my code:

```
function loadChatMessages(channelID) {
    $('#chatMessages').html('');
    var msgObj = {};
    var channelRef = globals.channelsBase + '/' + channelID + '/messages';

    var channelMessages = new Firebase(channelRef);
    channelMessages.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
        msgObj = snapshot.val();
        var id = snapshot.name().toString();

            var messageTime = application.Functions.renderTime(msgObj.messageTime);
            var tails = '<div class="message-tails-wrap"><div class="message-tails"></div></div>';
            var html = '<li class="chatEl ' + sentByClass + '" id="'+id+'">';
            html += tails;
            html += msgObj.message;
            html += '<span class="sender"> ' + by + ' </span> <span class="tmp-recipient"> ' + msgObj.recipient + ' </span>';
            html += '<span class="time-stamp msg-time" >';
            html += messageTime;
            html += '</span></li>';
            $(html).appendTo('#chatMessages');

        /// TODO: TEMP solution!
        var prevID = 0;
        $('#chatMessages li').each(function(n) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if(id == prevID){
               // console.log(id + ' is a duplicate. Remove it');
                this.remove(); // the necessary evil....                 
            }
            prevID = id;
        });

    });

}
```

Comment: I'd set a breakpoint or add a console.log to make sure your .on('child_added', ...) call isn't getting run multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried this already.
on('child_added,...) gets called multiple times when the channel loads first, then once a new message is added. This is expected. The issues start when I add a message to a different channel and then load my the previous channel. Then when I add  a new message on('child_added,...) gets called twice.

Comment: Yes, that's because .on("child_added") is being called twice. You need to make sure to call .off("child_added") before adding a new listener for a new channel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you run `loadChatMessages()` every time you enter a room, and as your users move around rooms, you're seeing duplicate calls to your `on('child_added'` callback.

This is because you're adding a new callback every time you re-enter a room. To resolve this, do some clean up when your users leave a room. In that clean up function, make sure you remove the old listener using `.off("child_added")`.

Answer (score 1):

The event :

```
YOURREF.limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function (OBJECTADDED){
    console.log(OBJECTADDED.key(), OBJECTADDED.val());
});
```

You may think the above code will e fired one time, this is not true. The above console.log will be fired twice, once with OBJECTADDED as the last object in the reference YOURREF before adding the new one, and another with the new one.