# Firebase Adding a call back for previous chat message

Tags: jquery, firebase

I want to add a callback for loading the previous messages upon clicking a user.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var messagesRef = new Firebase("https://fbname.firebaseIO.com/messages");
var userListRef = new Firebase("https://fbname.firebaseIO.com/userlist");   
userListRef.on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
        var user = snapshot.val();
        if (user.accessk != name) {
            $("<input type='radio' / >")
              .on("click", function () {
                var dt = $(this).val(), df = $(this).attr("data-fname"), dl = $(this).attr("data-lname"),
                       src = "temp/user/" + dt + ".jpg";

                messagesRef.child(child_id).update({ dtelog: Math.random() });
                messageList.html(""); });
            }

    });
    messagesRef.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
        var data = snapshot.val(), dtes = data.date, src = data.pic, sender = data.sender, reciever = data.reciever, message = data.text,
                     ui = checker, username = userN, style_c = "";
        if (sender != username) { style_c = "message chat"; }
        else { style_c = "message user"; }

        var messageElement = "Message here has HTMLtags";
        messageElement.find('.bubble').html(message);
        if (((sender == username) && (reciever == checker)) || ((sender == checker) && (reciever == username))) {

            //ADD MESSAGE
            messageList.append(messageElement);
        }
        messageList[0].scrollTop = messageList[0].scrollHeight;
    });
```

My idea was to add the `messagesRef.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {}` function inside the `$("<input type='radio' / >")`.

It displays the message correctly, but after I switch to another user to send message, the message displays twice. Then if I navigate back to the previous user, it displays thrice. I tried doing this for multiple times and the message increments by 1.

Who can explain why that happens?

Comment: Can you reduce the code to the minimum needed to reproduce the problem? Also, please include the lines that set up the `userListRef` and `messagesRef`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.. I managed to fix my own issue by browsing all of the articles regarding firebase and this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19019090/3444938) came like a miracle to me because I've been searching stack for an answer regarding my issue and never found this one since last week and I just found this an hour ago..

so what my solution became base on the article that I have provided looks like this

```
   messageList.html("");  
messagesRef.off('child_added');  
messagesRef.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
var data = snapshot.val(), dtes = data.dte, src = data.pic,sender = data.sender, reciever = data.reciever, message = data.text,
       ui =  checker, username = userN, style_c = "";
if (sender != username){ 
  style_c = "message chat";
} else  { 
  style_c = "message user";
  }

var messageElement = $('<div class="'+style_c+'"><div class="message-info">'+
     '<img width="40" height="40" src="temp/user/'+src+'.jpg">' +
         '<div class="message-timestamp">' +
         ' <time datetime="'+dtes+'" class="timeago uk-text-small">'+dtes+'</time>' +
         '</div></div>' +
       ' <div class="message-data">' +
       ' <div class="bubble"></div></div></div>');
    messageElement.find('.bubble').html(message).emoji();
 if (((sender == username) && (reciever == checker) )||((sender == checker) && (reciever == username) ))  
  {
       //ADD MESSAGE
        messageList.append(messageElement);
    }
   messageList[0].scrollTop = messageList[0].scrollHeight;
 });
```

I added `messagesRef.off('child_added')` to remove the listener 1st before proceeding to  call another `messagesRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot){});` that way even If I Navigate to another user to give him/her a private message the message display wont increment causing duplicate message displays. Although this is the answer I can come up with what I dont know is that if this kind of code structure is following the standards 
I would appreciate if someone could check this answer of mine if this is appropriate even though its working.. Thanks :)

Comment: Great job on figuring it out and +1 for coming back to update us on it.

Comment: Yeah, turning off your listeners becomes more important as you have single-page navigation elements. Great to see that the other question helped you. Can you accept your own answer? That way other will know that it was the proper solution to your problem.